# Running integration/e2e tests on top of a Kubernetes stack

Tags: testing, kubernetes, continuous-integration

I’ve been digging a bit into the way people run integration and e2e tests in the context of Kubernetes and have been quite disappointed by the lack of documentation and feedbacks. I know there are amazing tools such as kind or minikube that allow to run resources locally. But in the context of a CI, and with a bunch of services, it does not seem to be a good fit, for obvious resources reasons. I think there are great opportunities with running tests for:

- Validating manifests or helm charts
- Validating the well behaving of a component as part of a bigger whole
- Validating the global behaviour of a product

The point here is not really about the testing framework but more about the environment on top of which the tests could be run.

Do you share my thought? Have you ever experienced running such kind of tests? Do you have any feedbacks or insights about it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question and something that I have worked on over the last couple of months for my current employer. Essentially we ship a product as docker images with manifests. When writing e2e tests I want to run the product as close to the customer environment as possible.

Essentially to solve this we have built scripts that interact with our standard cloud provider (GCloud) to create a cluster, deploy the product and then run the tests against it.

For the major cloud providers this is not a difficult tasks but can be time consuming. There are a couple of things that we have learnt the hard way to keep in mind while developing the tests.

1. Concurrency, this may sound obvious but do think about the number of concurrent builds your CI can run.
2. Latency from the cloud, don't assume that you will get an instant response to every command that you run in the cloud. Also think about the timeouts. If you bring up a product with lots of pods and services what is the acceptable start up time?
3. Errors causing build failures, this is an interesting one. We have seen errors in the build due to network errors when communicating with our test deployment. These are nearly always transitive. It is best to avoid these making the build fail.

One thing to look at is GitLab are providing some [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html) on how to build and test images in their CI pipeline.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer @james-wilson. This is definitely a very valuable experience feedback. It must have taken you a lot of time for getting it ready for use. I got two questions that might be related to your second and third points actually :

Comment: - About the latency due to operations you delegate to your cloud provider, plus the startup time of your stack, how long does your entire CI pipeline take to go to completion ? I don't know if your already reached that point where you start having too many services running, but in terms of time, how would you compare the creation/deletion of your cluster comparing to the deployment of your services, and run of your tests ?

Comment: - My second point is about communicating with your cluster. How do you perform this ? Do you declare DNS entries which you need to wait until propagating or did you choose another way to talk to your services inside ? (e.g. port-forward or whatever)

Thank you for your time, I'm very interested in figuring myself the state of art of this topic.

Comment: hi @vensa, glad this helped. In terms of the time taken running the tests is the most time consuming step, followed by starting up the product and finally setup / tear down of the cluster. Our entire CI pipeline is rather complex and unfortunately we measure time in hours :( often spending time trying to make it faster! In terms of communication we are a little lazy and just use the external IP address that is assigned (in the service definition).

Comment: Wow waiting for your CI to run to completion during hours must definitely be painful. Would you still consider it as an interesting point to reduce the time of setup/tear down the cluster to zero ? 
And tell me if I'm wrong but so you get the definition of your services and extract the externalIP from it to communicate ? If that's the case it sounds fair as it satisfies your need. Didn't thing about this possibility.

Comment: `And tell me if I'm wrong but so you get the definition of your services and extract the externalIP from it to communicate` - Yes that is correct.

Comment: `Would you still consider it as an interesting point to reduce the time of setup/tear down the cluster to zero` - Personally no, this is 5mins of time out of a run measured in hours. It is somewhere between 2 and 5% of the total time, therefore I would rather spend the effort looking at how to run other aspects in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

1. On my side I use travis-ci. I build my container image inside it, then run k8s with kind (https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/) inside travis-CI, and then launch my e2e tests.

- Here is some additional information on this blog post: https://k8s-school.fr/resources/en/blog/k8s-ci/
- And the scripts to install kind inside travis-ci in 2 lines: https://github.com/k8s-school/kind-travis-ci.git. It allows lots of customization on the k8s side (enable psp, change CNI plugin)
- Here is an example: https://github.com/lsst/qserv-operator

2. Or I use Github Actions CI, which allows to install kind easily: https://github.com/helm/kind-action and provide plenty of features, and free worker nodes for open-source projects.

- Here is an example: https://github.com/xrootd/xrootd-k8s-operator

Please note that Github action workers may not scale for large build/e2e tests.  Travis-CI scales pretty well.

In my understanding, this workflow coud be moved to an on-premise gitlab CI where your application can interact with other services located inside your network.

One interesting thing is that you do not have to maitain a k8s cluster for your CI, kind will do it for you!